# Cluster linking in Apache Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, confluent-cloud

Can someone please confirm if Cluster Linking is available in Apache Kafka? Or its limited only to Confluent Kafka.

I have a requirement to link one VM based Confluent Platform cluster to another VM based Apache Kafka cluster. Hence trying to see if thats possible

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confluent *Server* or Confluent Cloud must be the destination cluster of the link, [per the documentation](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/multi-dc-deployments/cluster-linking/index.html)

MirrorMaker2 is the only builtin option to Apache Kafka for cluster replication.

There are other open source Kafka replication tools like [LinkedIn Brooklin](https://github.com/linkedin/Brooklin/) as well

Comment: Thanks @OneCrickteer for confirming this!